# on edit trigger for alertbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

my onedit trigger is currently working with timestamp but when I try to change the purpose, instead of timestamp it will show an alertbox that's where my code won't work, anyone can help me with this?

```
 var COLUMNTOCHECK = 2
  var SHEETNAME = 'trial';
  
function onEdit(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();  
  var testRange = selectedCell.offset(0, 1);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if(sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME) {  

  if(selectedCell.getValue() == "test"){
    ui.alert("popups",ui.ButtonSet.OK_Cancel);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is incorrect. `ui.ButtonSet.OK_Cancel` is not a valid [ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set). It should be `ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL`

### Code:

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 2
var SHEETNAME = 'trial';
  
function onEdit(){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();  
  var testRange = selectedCell.offset(0, 1);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if(sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME) {  

    if(selectedCell.getValue() == "test"){
      ui.alert("popups",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    }
  }
}
```

### **Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks man, I was just following code of alertbox in yt. i might have missed the caps lol what a terrible missed hehehe

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. By the way, just to give you some tips, to debug onEdit() you can check the execution tabs for possible error in your code if your code is not working as expected. I was able to find the issue regarding the button using that :) (don't forget to edit your sheet first to trigger the function)

Comment: I'll take note of that

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'trial' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value == "test") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("popups", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  }
}
```